# Non empty interior in the image implies open map

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category, open-map

I am looking at the proof showing that $L^2(0,1)$ is meager in $L^1(0,1)$. Define $B_n = \{f\in L^2 : \|f\|_2 \leq n\}$. With the continuous identity map $T:L^2 \rightarrow L^1$, if one of $T(B_n)$ has non empty interior, then $T$ is an open map, thus $T$ is onto which is a contradiction. Therefore, all of the image $T(B_n)$ has empty interior (and closed) thus $T(L^2) = T(\bigcup_n B_n)$ is meager in $L^1$.

My question is, how do we get from one $T(B_n)$ has non empty interior in $L^1$ to $T$ is an open map?  The solution makes this looks very trivial, but I just couldn't see it.

Comment: It is a general fact of linear mappings. Consider a linear mapping $T\colon X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces. Let $B\subset X$ denote the open unit ball. You can prove that $T$ is open if and only if $T(B)$ is a neighborhood of the origin in $Y$.

Comment: Why not use the fact that every $f\in L^2$ is the $L^1$ limit of a sequence of functions in $L^1\setminus L^2?$

Comment: Thank you guys for the hint, I posted one method of seeing this. @GiuseppeNegro I agree with your statement, but I do not see how to derive that the image of a ball centered at $f$ in $B_n$ is a open neighborhood of  $T(f)$ in $L^1$ from $B_n$ has non empty interior. Unless preimage of open balls are also open balls for continuous linear maps.

Comment: Xiao and @GiuseppeNegro is the 'IV' in Mindlack's answer here ([Does open map imply dimension of domain is greater than or equal to dimension of range? (please don't use sard's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110719/does-open-map-imply-dimension-of-domain-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-dimension-of/4122194#4122194)) related? it says open (and smooth) implies image has non-empty interior.

Comment: Xiao and @zhw. is the 'IV' in Mindlack's answer here ([Does open map imply dimension of domain is greater than or equal to dimension of range? (please don't use sard's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110719/does-open-map-imply-dimension-of-domain-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-dimension-of/4122194#4122194)) related? it says open (and smooth) implies image has non-empty interior.

Comment: @BCLC: frankly, I don't know. My old comment relates to a standard and easy fact of linear maps, whereas that answer concerns invariance of domain, which is a much more complicated theorem of differential topology. I wouldn't see too many connections between these two things.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I think I have the answer.

Method One:
Take $f\in B_n$ and $g\in L^1\setminus L^2$, then $f+\frac{g}{n}$ would be a sequence in $L^1\setminus L^2$ which converges to $f$ in $L^1$. This would show that each $T(B_n)$ has empty interior, because the tail of this sequence is contained in any $L^1$ ball of $T(f)$.

Okay, here is the second method, Let $T:L^2\rightarrow L^1$ be the inclusion map. And denote $B_1(f,r)$ and $B_2(f,r)$ be open ball in $L^1$ and $L^2$.

Now if $T(\overline{B_2(0,n)})$ has non-empty interior in $L^1$, then there exists a $L^1$-open ball that is contained in $T(\overline{B_2(0,n)})$, let us write this $L^1$-open ball as $f_0 + rB_1(0,1)$, note that $f_0$ is in $\overline{B_2(0,n)}$, thus 
$$rB_1(0,1) \subset T(\overline{B_2(0,n)})- f_0\subset T(\overline{B_2(0,2n)})$$
and this means for some constant $M$, we have 
$$MB_1(0,1) \subset T(B_2(0,1)).$$
This says the image of the unit ball in $L^2$ is a open neightborhood of $0$ in $L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

Anther way to show that if some $T(B_n)$ has non-empty interior in $L^1,$ then $T$ is an open map :

For $r>0$ let $B_r=\{f\in L^2: \|f\|_2\leq x\}.$ Then $T(B_r)=(r/s)T(B_s)=\{(r/s)T(f): f\in B_s\}$ for all positive $r,s$. So if int$_{L^1}\;T(B_r)\ne \phi$ for some $r>0$ then int$_{L^1}\;T(B_r)\ne \emptyset$ for all $r>0.$ 
Suppose this happens.

Let $U$ be open in $L^2$. For each $f\in U$ take $r(f)>0$ such that $V_f=\{g\in L^2:\|g-f\|_2<r(f)\}\subset U.$ Take $g_f\in B_{r(f)/2}$ such that $T(g_f)\in W_f\subset T(B_{r(f)/2})$ where $W_f$ is open in $ L^1.$

Then  $T(f)\in W_f+T(f-g_f) \subset T(V_f)\subset T(U),$ while  $W_f+T(f-g_f)=\{h+T(f-g_f):h\in W_f\}$ is open in $L^1.$

So $T(U)=\cup_{f\in U}(\;W_f+T(f-g_f)\;)$ is open in $L^1.$

Note: This applies if we replace $L^2, L^1$ with any two normed linear spaces $X, Y$ and any linear $T:X\to Y.$

Comment: DanielWainfleet, is the 'IV' in Mindlack's answer here ([Does open map imply dimension of domain is greater than or equal to dimension of range? (please don't use sard's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110719/does-open-map-imply-dimension-of-domain-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-dimension-of/4122194#4122194)) related? it says open (and smooth) implies image has non-empty interior.

Comment: @BCLC . That is a Q about finite-dimensional manifolds. I don't see an immediate relation.

Comment: thanks DanielWainfleet!